# CVAT localhost not uploading images

Tags: docker, computer-vision, object-detection, cvat

I have installed CVAT on local (via Docker) but when trying to upload images from the local storage, it's simply stuck. It says "The data are being uploaded to the server" and is stuck at 0%. I tested with every kind of image file, big or small.

On the network tab it makes requests to http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/10/status?org= and keeps returning

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, already solved [here](https://github.com/opencv/cvat/issues/5448).